# Adding a project reference in Visual Studio when using lock file (package.lock.json)

Tags: .net-4.8, lockfile

I have a solution with many .net framework 4.8 projects and some .net standard projects. We recently added lockfiles to the projects. Projects have `RestoreLockedMode` property set to `true`.

When updating/installing nuget package, the lockfiles are automatically updated as needed.

The problem is, when I add a project reference to a project, the lock file is *not* updated, resulting in a `NU1004` error.

Currently my workaround is building with command line setting `RestoreLockedMode=false` :

```
msbuild.exe ./mysolution.sln -t:restore,build -p:RestoreLockedMode=false
```

with this line, packages lock are updated. Is there a way Visual Studio could do the job when adding the reference ? The command line works, but it's far from optimal when 40 diffent dev works on the project, and not everyone understantds what's going on.